# How to display a windows/X window system window in 3d space on texture?

Tags: windows, linux, 3d, desktop

I'm wondering, how can I catch a window and display it on texture in 3D space. And how can I redirect mouse and keyboard input from 3D application to application running in background? I mean full 3D desktop.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a bit complex, and a "full" answer might not be suitable for this forum. Here's an idea/outline, though:

One way of doing it is through [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/). Run a separate, invisible "virtual" desktop in a VNC server, then start the desired apps with it as the display. Your 3D rendering program on the "real" desktop can then connect to the VNC server, and get access to its desktop in bitmap format, and blast that onto textured polygons. Piping in input events is very doable, too.

I've actually done this, or at least half of it (the display). Here is a very old screenshot of what I managed to do, back then:
[image]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://verse.sourceforge.net/shots/vnc-screen.png))</sub>
The black sky and blue/purple-ish "ground" are rendered by the 3D program on the real desktop, while the slanted quad shows a window in the "virtual" VNC desktop.

Fun!

Answer (score 0):

A key part of the solution is the OpenGL/GLX extension [`GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_from_pixmap.txt) which bridges the gap between the X11 and OpenGL worlds.

As to the rest... [Compiz](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Compiz) and [CompizFusion](http://wiki.compiz-fusion.org/) already implement 3D desktops.  Give 'em a try; if you've got some specific ideas about the way things should work the sources are freely available (and they also support the idea of plugins).